# How can I pipe external html content in jade?

Tags: node.js, gulp, pug

I'm trying to get some html from a page online and place inside my jade template so I can style without copying and pasting every time a need it.

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var loadContent = function() { 
   request({
      uri: "http://www.mywebsite.com.br/test"
   }, function(error, response, body) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      var result;
      $('.content').each(function(){
         result={"content":$(this).html()};
      });
      placeContent(result);
      return true;
   });
};
var placeContent = function(content) {
  return content;
};
module.exports = loadContent;
```

Inside my gulpfile.js, besides the right requirements, I have:

```
gulp.task('jadeBuild', function() {
  var options = {
    pretty: true
  };
  return gulp.src(src+'/*.jade')
    .pipe(data(function(){
        return loadContent();
    }))
    .pipe(jade(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

And my jade file:

```
.mycontent
  #{content}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `#{content}` to `!{content}` in your jade file. This will tell jade not to escape any of the characters(which can be dangerous depending on where the input is coming from!).

See http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Also, when you loop over each `.content` you are overwriting `result` every time. You need to append to result if you want to aggregate all the content together. Something like:

```
var result = {content: ''};
$('.content').each(function(){
   result.content += $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: This helped a bit. But I think the problem is asynchronous. The html content is not returning in time to populate the variable; I'm open to suggestions. :)